# Isomorphic objects in the derived category

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-categories

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category, $D(\mathcal{A})$ be its derived category and $X,Y$ be complexes with morphisms in $\mathcal{A}$. I am trying to understand what does it mean to say that $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic in $D(\mathcal{A})$. Obviously, if there is a quasi-isomorphism $X \longrightarrow Y$, then these complexes are isomorphic in $D(\mathcal{A})$, but does the converse hold? I have two questions:

1. If $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic in $D(\mathcal{A})$, then is it true that there is a quasi-isomorphism $X \longrightarrow Y$?
2. If $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic in $D(\mathcal{A})$, then there is a (left) fraction $(s,f) : X \longrightarrow Y$, where $s : Z \longrightarrow X$ is a quasi-isomorphism and $f: Z \longrightarrow Y$ is a morphism of complexes (modulo homotopy), such that $(s,f)$ is an isomorphism in $D(\mathcal{A})$. In this case, is it true that $f$ is also a quasi-isomorphism?

I will be also grateful for any explanation or idea which may clarify the meaning of two complexes being isomorphic in the derived category.

Comment: 1. No. Consider $X:0\to 0\to \mathbb Z/2\to 0,Y:0\to \mathbb Z\stackrel{\cdot 2}{\to}\mathbb Z\to 0$ (padded with zeros in both directions) in $D(Ab)$. There is no nonzero $X\to Y$, hence no quasiisomorphism $X\to Y$, yet they are isomorphic in $D(Ab)$ since there is a quasiisomorphism $Y\to X$. We can strengthen it to show there needn't be a quasiisomorphism either way, by making a complex $X'$ which contians a copy of $X$ and $Y$, and $Y'$ which contains copies of $Y$ and $X$ in corresponding spaces.

Comment: 2. If we assume the fraction $(s,f)$ is an isomorphism in $D(\mathcal A)$ (which you didn't explicitly state), then yes, as then also $f$ is an isomorphism in $D(\mathcal A)$, hence (as cohomology is a well-defined functor on $D(\mathcal A)$) it induces isomorphism on all cohomology.

Comment: @Wojowu Thank you, I edited the question.

Comment: 1. In fact, $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic in $D( \mathcal(A))$ if there exist a finite zig-zag $X \stackrel{\sim }{\rightarrow} X' \stackrel{\sim }{\leftarrow} ... \stackrel{\sim }{\rightarrow} Y' \stackrel{\sim }{\leftarrow} Y$.
If the category has enough projectives or enough injectives, you can using the theory of model categories. Then you can control the length of the zigzag (it's always of length three).

Comment: @MoreatuT I guess the composition of roofs (or zig-zags as you call them) $X\leftarrow X'\to\cdots\leftarrow Y'\to Y$ is another roof $X\leftarrow Z\to Y$. So $X\cong Y$ in $D(\mathcal{A})$ if and only if there is a roof $X\leftarrow Z\to Y$ in which both morphisms are quasi-isomorphisms.

Comment: @Wojowu, You meant here that $f$ is a quasi-isomorphism (hence an isomorphism in the derived category), right?